# Can't save project. (error 500)

Tags: gitlab

When I try to create new project, gitlab (v 6.3.0) shows the 500 error page.

Gitlab log:

```
==> production.log <==
Started POST "/projects" for xx.xx.xx. at 2013-12-22 22:28:29 +0000
Processing by ProjectsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"dJm8MC7Za8d+kJjCdUe88O2nzS1g7bW8uHLpQ08h+Y8=", "project"=>{"name"=>"test2", "path"=>"", "namespace_id"=>"1", "import_url"=>"", "description"=>""}, "commit"=>"Create project"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 136.5ms

NoMethodError (undefined method errors' for nil:NilClass):
app/contexts/projects/create_context.rb:60:inrescue in execute'
app/contexts/projects/create_context.rb:9:in execute'
app/controllers/projects_controller.rb:23:increate'
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:54:in `set_current_user_for_thread'
```

I thing, gitlab is trying to execute this line:

```
@project.errors.add(:base, "Can't save project. Please try again later")
```

Gitlab will not create repository in the repository path. How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This issue was /maybe/ solved by upgrading gitlab to version 6.4.3